# Jquery Datatables: Set page from rowId

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to set the default page from a recordId.
After taken a look to: https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId
I have set a the rowsIds on my table:

```
$('#logosTable').DataTable(
            {
                serverSide: true,
                processing: true,
                searching: true,
                autoWidth: true,
                responsive: true,
                dom: 'rtip',
                ajax: {
                    url: '/Administracion/App/ObtenerListadoLogos',
                    type: "POST",
                    data:
                        function (d) {
                            d.DefaultLogo = $("#IdLogo").val()
                        }
                },
                rowId: 'Id',
                columns: [
                    { data: 'Id' },
                    {
                        data: 'Logo',
                        searchable: false,
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<img src="/DataBackend/ThumbnailsGallery/1/' + data + '" style="width:50px" />';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'acciones',
                        searchable: false,
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<a href="#" onclick="seleccionarLogo(' + row.Id + ', \'' + row.Fichero + '\')"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Seleccionar </a>';
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
```

**How can I set the default init page from a record id?**

I have tried this: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnDisplayRow
Howver on 1.10, it seems is no longer available.
I have taken a look to: https://datatables.net/reference/api/
But it seems this functionality (and fngetNodes) has gone away.

Comment: `fnDisplayRow` is a plugin that you need to include separately, and there's an example using `fnGetNodes()` for 1.10 right on the `fnDisplayRow` documentation page.

Comment: @J.Titus I will accept it as the accepted ansewer if you write it

Comment: Added as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fnDisplayRow` is a plugin that you need to include separately from the main DataTables library:

https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/api/fnDisplayRow.js

There's an example using `fnGetNodes()` for 1.10 on the `fnDisplayRow` [documentation page](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnDisplayRow):

```
// Display the nth row in the table
var table = $('#example').dataTable();
table.fnDisplayRow( table.fnGetNodes()[n] );
```